# Ubuntu linux-image-generic-lts-xenial 4.4.0.108.91 not covering Spectre Vulnerabilities

Tags: kernel

Why are we still seeing Spectre Vulnerabilities exists even though we patched our kernel version to `-- linux-image-generic-lts-xenial 4.4.0.108.91`?

We've attached the image of our upgrade.

[image]

We request you to let us know what we can do further to be secured.

Comment: I think the patch is `4.4.0.109.231` or so!

Comment: That kernel -108 is indeed vulnerable. Upgrade to -109 (in xenial-security)

Comment: Tried updating to kernel as per advisory ..                                               
linux-image-generic-lts-xenial 4.4.0.109.92
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-xenial 4.4.0.109.92
linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic 4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1 But still am seeing its vulnerable as per the Spectre. Can you pls provide any inputs on the same. Thanks much.

Comment: Read the wiki page. It clearly states the two Spectre CVEs will be mitigated via patches in a second round of updates, as they are not yet ready.

Comment: Is the spectre vulerability mitigated versions are also released by chance, am following security advisory somehow not able to get desired details. If any one could share that should be perfect. We are protected with meltdown, but would like to check for Spectre as well for 14.04 Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 1):

Look here for patch kernels to Ubuntu systems:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown

The steps are found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades, but see first link first.

Comment: Tried updating to kernel as per advisory .. linux-image-generic-lts-xenial 4.4.0.109.92 linux-image-lowlatency-lts-xenial 4.4.0.109.92 linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic 4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1 But still am seeing its vulnerable as per the Spectre. Can you pls provide any inputs on the same. Thanks much